# Calculate Total Price from multiple toggle Buttons

Tags: java, android

Am trying to calculate the total price using Toggle buttons to add and remove prices.

My code is below but the logic is not quite right.

As you can see I am trying to add different packages to the total price on a textview at the top of the activity.

Each toggle button carries a different price that when clicked it will add that value to the total price displayed on the top. At the moment I am checking when the toggle button is checked and I add the price which works fine for the first button and the second, but when I try to substract it goes wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :

```
private void getAdditionalPackagePremiums() {

    premiumTitlePrice = PetplanInsuranceBase.getInstance().getPetplanInsuranceModel().getPremium_amount();

    chemoButtonPrice = PetplanInsuranceBase.getInstance().getPetplanInsuranceModel().getChemo_price();
    cremationButtonPrice = PetplanInsuranceBase.getInstance().getPetplanInsuranceModel().getCremation_price();
    travelButtonPrice = PetplanInsuranceBase.getInstance().getPetplanInsuranceModel().getTravel_price();


    premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + premiumTitlePrice);

    //Chemo Button
    chemoBtn.setText("+ Voeg toe (+ € " + chemoButtonPrice + "/mnd )");
    chemoBtn.setTextOff("+ Voeg toe (+ € " + chemoButtonPrice + "/mnd )");
    chemoBtn.setTextOn("Toegevoegd (+ € " + chemoButtonPrice + "/mnd )");

    //Cremation Button
    cremBtn.setText("+ Voeg toe (+ € " + cremationButtonPrice + "/mnd )");
    cremBtn.setTextOff("+ Voeg toe (+ € " + cremationButtonPrice + "/mnd )");
    cremBtn.setTextOn("Toegevoegd (+ € " + cremationButtonPrice + "/mnd )");

    //Travel Button
    travenBtn.setText("+ Voeg toe (+ € " + travelButtonPrice + "/mnd )");
    travenBtn.setTextOff("+ Voeg toe (+ € " + travelButtonPrice + "/mnd )");
    travenBtn.setTextOn("Toegevoegd (+ € " + travelButtonPrice + "/mnd )");

    d = Double.valueOf(premiumTitlePrice);

    //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(d), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void setListeners() {

    //boolean chemoIsChecked = false;

    chemoBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Double chemoPrice = Double.valueOf(chemoButtonPrice);
                Totalprice = chemoPrice + d;
                totalPrice = String.valueOf(Totalprice);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                d = Totalprice;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity.this, "NotChecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Double chemoPrice = Double.valueOf(chemoButtonPrice);
                Double notalprice = Totalprice - chemoPrice;
                totalPrice = String.valueOf(notalprice);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                d = notalprice;
            }
        }
    });

    cremBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Double cremPrice = Double.valueOf(cremationButtonPrice);
                Totalprice = cremPrice + d;
                totalPrice = String.valueOf(Totalprice);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                d = Totalprice;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity.this, "NotChecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Double cremPrice = Double.valueOf(cremationButtonPrice);
                Double notalprice = Totalprice - cremPrice;
                totalPrice = String.valueOf(notalprice);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                d = notalprice;
            }
        }

    });


}
```

}

[image]

Comment: try to debug to check when the price get changed and try to check a correct scénario , check when the price is valid or not

Comment: Can you show how your toggle buttons work? I mean its screenshot so that I can get an idea of what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below Method, This is the implementation of "setListeners" method. What I observed, that you are mixing your logic in between TotalPrice and d, so taking them as single. And One more thing I observed that you have taken listeners for chemoBtn, cremebtn but not travenBtn, take listener for this toggle button too if required.

```
private void setListeners() {

    //boolean chemoIsChecked = false;

    chemoBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Double chemoPrice = Double.valueOf(chemoButtonPrice);
                d = chemoPrice + d;
                String totalPrice = String.valueOf(Totalprice);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity.this, "NotChecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Double chemoPrice = Double.valueOf(chemoButtonPrice);
                d = d - chemoPrice;
                String totalPrice = String.valueOf(d);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
            }
        }
    });

    cremBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Double cremPrice = Double.valueOf(cremationButtonPrice);
                d = cremPrice + d;
                String totalPrice = String.valueOf(d);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity.this, "NotChecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Double cremPrice = Double.valueOf(cremationButtonPrice);
                d = d - cremPrice;
                String totalPrice = String.valueOf(d);
                premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks! And yes I will add the listener for the last button too! I was lost in my logic! I added an edit because it was returning null, other than that it works great! Thank you!